# How to install mbedtls package?

Tags: debian

How to install mbedtls_2.16.0-1.debian.tar.xz available on https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/mbedtls?

Comment: Are you running Sid? Please update your post with the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apt-src` , install the `apt-src` tool:

```
apt install apt-src
```

Enable the source urls in your [`/etc/apt/sources.list`](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) then run:

```
apt-src update
apt-src install mbedtls
apt-src build mbedtls
```

Use `dpkg` to install the created packages.

[Debian: apt-src](https://wiki.debian.org/apt-src)

[README and configuration options for Mbed TLS](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/mbedtls)